# Report Parameter showing detailed report

Tags: sql-server

I want to display 2 different reports in single parameter. If I select any of one parameter value then it will execute selected parameter value report.

For Example: I created 2 reports which are  1. Report Total 2. Report Details

I knew that you can do with textbox and go to property and select action and do hyperlink but I really want to do in Report Parameter.

Can anyone help me how to do this in SSRS ??

Answer (score 0):

Just write the details report with a totals row. Use your parameter to set Visible=True/False on your detail row. If you do this, I am sure you will get an A.

**EDIT: responding to your comments.**

I don't think you want two different .rdl files. One should do. Put everything in one report and then use EXPRESSIONS to change the look based on your parameter value.

```
=if(Parameters!@Report.Value="Detail", True, False)
```

Comment: But I didn't understand your answer very well.

Comment: Lets Say: There is 1 report. Now on that report I want to pur 1 parameter which is called Report and It is having 2 value: Details and Totals. Now Details and Totals are both different .rdl file. So, if you select Total from Report Parameter then will execute Total.rdl report and if you select Detail from Report parameter then it will execute Details.rdl.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do this with a parameter, you would change your hyperlink / code to open the required report.  The architecture doesn't support what you are trying to do without doing something *hacky*.

Comment: Hi CK, Yor are right. Correct me If I m wrong. I believe This is not possible using parameter to invoke 2 different report that having different datasets but as per Bill's logic It will work if both report pulling data from same datasets.